# Bundle.js is not creating after the command - node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, browserify

I am trying to create the bundle.js with the help of browserify but its givng me error :

```
npm WARN invalid config registry="app/main:app"
npm WARN invalid config Must be a full url with 'http://'
```

This is the command i am trying to hit

```sh
$ browserify -r ./app/main:app > static/bundle.js
```

This is my folder structure.

[image]

Comment: how are you executing the browserify command? via your package.json? if so, could you paste the relevant code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

browserify requires a javascript file as an entry point. So it should look like this:

```
browserify app/main.js > static/bundle.js
```